# JS - Scope chain

Tags: javascript

I thought scope chain would make the first "test = new test();" work, but it doesn't. why?

```
var tool = new Tool();
tool.init();

function Tool(){
    var test;

    function init(){
        //does not work, undefined
        test = new Test();

        //does work
        this.test=new Test();

        console.log(test);
    }
}

function Test(){
}
```

**EDIT: by not working i mean, it says that test is 'undefined'**

Comment: It should. Question is, what are you trying to do? Your code means nothing.

Comment: There's not enough code here to say exactly what's going on.  How is `init` called?  How do you try to access `test`?

Comment: by work i mean undefined. Added some code above

Comment: where do you define the class "Test"?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That code will not work for a dozen reasons: function used before declaration; undeclared variable test; missing ``Test()`` function, ``init()`` *not* declared as a method, but just as function inside another function, ....

Comment: added test function location

Comment: @user1789469 In your code above, the `init` local function is never invoked, so nothing is logged to the console. Also, `tool.init();` throws an error, since no such method is defined on `tool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Your `Tool` instance does not have a `init` method. The `init` function in your code is merely a local function of the `Tool` constructor. `Tool` instances do not inherit such functions.

If you want your `Tool` instances to have a `init` method, you can:

1. assign it as a method inside the constructor:

   ```
   function Tool () {
       this.init = function () { ... };
   }
   ```
2. or assign it to `Tool.prototype` (outside of the constructor!):

   ```
   Tool.prototype.init = function () { ... };
   ```

The second option performs better, since all instances share the same `init` function. (In the first option, each instance gets its own `init` function which is created during the constructor call.)

Comment: While that's certainly a problem with his example code, I think the question is about varriables inside init, and he just overlooked the incorrect function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access `test` in the scope of Tool, or on the object returned by it? They are two different variables. I've labeled them A and B:

```
var tool = new Tool();

function Tool(){
    var testA; // Private

    this.init = function(){
        testA = 1;

        this.testB = 9; // Public
    }

    this.getTestA = function(){ // Public method to access the private testA
        return testA;
    }

}

tool.init();

console.log( tool.getTestA() ); // 1
console.log( tool.testB ); // 9
```

`testA` is known as a Private variable, only accessible through Tool's methods, while `testB` is public.

Does this cover what you're looking for?

By the way, if you're making a lot of instances of Tool, remember to use Tool's prototype to define the functions instead, so your code is more memory efficient, like so:

```
function Tool(){
    var testA;
}
Tool.prototype.init = function(){
    testA = 1;
    this.testB = 9;
}
Tool.prototype.getTestA = function(){  return testA; }
```